# How to analyse multiple texts in a single request using CommunitySentiment Model of Salesforce Einstein?

Tags: nlp, salesforce, sentiment-analysis, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-einstein

I was working on text analysis and wanted to classify text as `Positive`, `Negative`, or `Neutral`. Salesforce Einstein's Community Model has been successful in achieving the task. However, the main problem I am facing is:

Currently to analyze each text, I need to make a separate request. Since I have 1000s of records I cannot make such required number of requests to Salesforce Einstein. Is there a workaround for this problem?

This is my function call, which takes a parameter `textStatus` - A single text statement.

```
apiCall(SENTIMENT, textStatus, 'CommunitySentiment');
```

I want to pass all text records as a list or in another way that ensures the whole task being performed in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

[Community Sentiment Model](https://metamind.readme.io/docs/use-pre-built-models-sentiment) is just pre-built sentiment model, which provides pretty simple classification classes like 'positive', 'negative' or 'neutral'. That just means that you can use this model when you don't want to train your own model.

And it, unfortunately, don't provide any capabilities to process bunch of texts per one request.